# Chrome issues with CSS Grid styled buttons

Tags: html, css, reactjs, grid

I've been struggling to make CSS Grid work on buttons on Chromium. It works fine with Firefox but on Chromium there's something wrong going on. The grid is displayed as if there was no second column defined.

Here's the basic code:

```
<button className="container">
   <div className="header"></div>
   <div className="child"></div>
   <div className="child"></div>
   <div className="child"></div>
   <div className="child"></div>
</button>
```

and here's the basic CSS code:

```
.container {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
   grid-template-rows: 2.5rem repeat(3, 1fr);
   gap: 0.5rem;
}

.header {
   grid-row: 1 / 1;
   grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
```

Applying this code to the button gives the following result:

[Grid layout with button element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYaBk.png)

It doesn't behave as intended. Changing the tag from 'button' to 'div' makes it work properly on Chrome:

[Grid layout with div element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqoIC.png)

Of course I set outline to 0 and all that stuff. Firefox seems to display both properly.

As using div with onClick property isn't a good solution what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
<button>
   <div className="container">
       <div className="header"></div>
       <div className="child"></div>
       <div className="child"></div>
       <div className="child"></div>
       <div className="child"></div>
   </div>
</button>
```

Comment: Yeah, it works, thanks for the solution, but doesn't it all seem like an odd behavior?

Comment: I've seen similair posts like yours where these grid buttons work fine on Firefox but not on Chrome. Some say it's a bug.